# Does Title IX require U.S. universities to have grade expungement policies?

Tags: united-states, grades, legal-issues, gender

Under U.S. law, Title IX sets requirements on how universities must deal with sex discrimination, including making reasonable accommodations for victims of assault or harassment.  One possible accommodation is grade expungement (removing courses from a transcript if the grades were affected by this situation).  Are universities required to have a publicly stated policy on this issue, or can they handle it on a case by case basis?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  The question isn't worded well, but it seems like a perfectly reasonable question about academic practices in the U.S.  Title IX is a law dealing with sex discrimination in education, and among other things it requires universities to make reasonable accommodations for victims of assault or harassment.  One possible accommodation is removing courses from a transcript if the grades were affected by this situation, and the question is whether universities are required to have a publicly stated policy on this issue, or whether they can handle it on a case by case basis.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician I have added "Under US law" at the beginning, in benefit of those that, like me, didn't understand.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician, the details you provide in the comment are critical in understanding the question. Please edit it in.

Answer (score 9):

Schools don't have to create an expungement policy, though it's strongly suggested by the Department of Education's Office of Civil Rights.

Per the Violence Against Women Act (VAWA), which amended Title IX, universities are required to make "reasonable accommodations" for survivors. Universities have [some latitude](https://www.federalregister.gov/articles/2014/10/20/2014-24284/violence-against-women-act#p-151) in what they may deem reasonable or not and furthermore may decide whether or not to grant such an accommodation on a case-by-case basis. Thus, there is no general answer to your question.

Of course, given that the accommodation you're asking about has [showed up as a suggestion in official Office of Civil Rights communications](http://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/know-rights-201404-title-ix.pdf), there's a pretty good chance that your university offers something along those lines. The Office of Civil Rights (OCR) investigates and sues schools for failure to comply with Title IX, among other things, so their "suggestions" carry some weight.

Universities are required to let students know what sorts of accommodations they offer, and how students may go about requesting them. Identify your college's Title IX coordinator, and ask them whether or not your college offers expungement as an accommodation, and how to go about requesting it.